# AZURE - Save VM ARM Template to Templates

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I am trying to save ARM Template of VM into the Templates in Azure but I am getting the following error:

> The client 'admin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com' with object id '1550f813-ee2g-492e-b353-8885c1f85746' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Gallery/register/action' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Gallery' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for the above :

- You can use **Template Specs** feature instead of **Templates** feature.
- You can ask your **Azure Active Directory tenant admin** to create the first
  gallery template to turn on the ability to create templates for all users under
  the same tenant.

**Steps to Create Template Spec:**

1. Go to Template Specs in portal.
2. Select Create template spec.

[image]

3. Fill in the form and create .

**Note:** Templates with the same name will be overridden by the latest version.

**Reference:**

[Convert portal template to template spec - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-spec-convert)

[Azure Templates - Failed to save template - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/490572/azure-templates-failed-to-save-template.html)